# Why does dumping DateTime to :utc_datetime_usec with a precision less than 6 fail?

Tags: elixir, ecto, postgrex

I am wondering why I can't dump a `DateTime` with a precision less than 6? Why can't we just fill up with zeros?

### Example

```
iex> {:ok, datetime, _} = DateTime.from_iso8601("1970-01-01T00:00:00Z")
{:ok, #DateTime<1970-01-01 00:00:00Z>, 0}
```

#### Expected

```
iex> Ecto.Type.dump(:utc_datetime_usec, datetime)
{:ok, #DateTime<1970-01-01 00:00:00.000000Z>}
```

#### Actual

```
iex> Ecto.Type.dump(:utc_datetime_usec, datetime)
** (ArgumentError) :utc_datetime_usec expects microsecond precision, got: #DateTime<1970-01-01 00:00:00Z>
    (ecto) lib/ecto/type.ex:1217: Ecto.Type.check_usec!/2
    (ecto) lib/ecto/type.ex:419: Ecto.Type.dump_utc_datetime_usec/1
```

Comment: What is your question? Why would you expect _Ecto_ to make a [possibly erroneous] guesses about your intent instead of explicitly telling “you are doing it wrong”? Please note, that the actual value, in this case, _does not have a `usec` defined_ which is absolutely not the same as _having it defined to be zeroes_.

Comment: Okay, got it :-) That's what I wanted to know!

Answer (score 0):

As the type name says, `utc_datetime_usec` does expect usec precision. So giving it anything with less precision will make it fail. You can use `utc_datetime` if you don't want to enforce microseconds.

Comment: But why? If your are getting the `DateTime.from_iso8601/1`, depending on the original encoder, the trailing zeros could be truncated (from the same reason we have `0.1` and not `0.1000`). And there is no easy way (from standard library) to increase / guarantee precision when parsing to DateTime.

Would you acceps `DateTime.upscale(dt, :microseconds)` in standard lib?